# 3D in the web? WebGL, etc

Tags: 3d, webgl

I'm trying to get started with some 3D Webdesigning. The question now is, where to start.

For now I only know "WebGL". Will WebGL be the main 3D library? Are there others to look at?

The support from browsers right now is mostly only partial, but I think it would be a good idea to start of now, as in the future more and more 3D websites will be built.

So is WebGL the right thing for me? Are there other possibilities? Will the support grow or will it be more likely, that CSS4 and further versions will take place of the 3D graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the desired level of abstraction.
WebGL itself has a lower level of abstraction, you must know computer graphics pretty well since it's kinda similar to OpenGL ES.
Luckily a lot of WebGL based framework with an higher level of abstraction are now available, such as Three.js, Babylon.js, PhiloGL and many others, each one with its own pro and cons.
Moreover, X3D and X3DOM (sponsored and developed by Web3D Consortium) are two frameworks inspired by the "declarative 3D" concept, basically 3D with XML, and they actually are an evolution of VRML.
At its actual state X3D still depends on web plugins to run inside a browser window but you can encapsulate X3D files inside of X3DOM files which instead run natively.
I don't know much about CSS4 so I won't express about it but I think that WebGL and its higher level frameworks are a valid choice for the 3d web right now.